# how to show image in full screen when pressed?

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `SlidingSplashScreen` library to slide between images and to show small dots below the images to keep track of the image I am showing. So my question is how to show images in full screen when pressed? I have tried the below solution by @Haresh Chhelana but it didn't work:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imageView;

boolean isImageFitToScreen;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isImageFitToScreen) {
                isImageFitToScreen=false;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            }else{
                isImageFitToScreen=true;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            }
        }
    });

  }
}
```

and the below is my code, the main activity is:

```
package com.hodhod.myapplication;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;



import com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int[] images = {

        R.drawable.escapers,
        R.drawable.escapers2,
        R.drawable.facebook,
        R.drawable.facebook


};

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SlidingSplashView slidingSplashView = (SlidingSplashView) findViewById(R.id.sliding_splash_view);

    slidingSplashView.setImageResources(images);


  }

}
```

and that is the activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView
    android:id="@+id/sliding_splash_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

</com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add clickListener on images. Something like this :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
  inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,false);

  final ImageView image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  DisplayMetrics dis = new DisplayMetrics();
  activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dis);
  int height = dis.heightPixels;
  int width = dis.widthPixels;
  image.setMinimumHeight(height);
  image.setMinimumWidth(width);

  itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        // here you can show the image in fullscreen
        // First method : use an hidden fullscreen Layout (like the first piece of code you've posted)
        // Second method : use an Activity
    }
  try {
    Picasso.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
            .load(images[position])
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(image);
  }
  catch (Exception ex){

  }

  container.addView(itemView);
  return itemView;
}
```

Comment: i have removed unnecessary code and that is the my final code, thank you for answering i wish you have another look at the code @Bruno

Comment: Wow...code has changed in the full way... I have a look at your lib and I saw that there is a [onItemClickListener](https://github.com/Chabbal/slidingdotsplash/blob/master/slidingdotsplash/src/main/java/com/chabbal/slidingdotsplash/OnItemClickListener.java) which gives you the position of the selected image. With this, you're able to find the desired image.

Comment: i can get the position of each image but i can't make it in full screen when pressed. i have tried to setLayoutparams but it doesn't work on SlidingSplashScreen view i have to get an ImageView to apply setLayotParams to it, but i can't do so. can you please guide me to a way so i can get the image in full screen when pressed, thank you @Bruno

Comment: You don't have to change layout params related to your `SlidingSplashView`. Instead, you have to display the image on a Dialog, on a fullscreen layout or on other Activity